# Writing a partial sum of Fourier series as an integral

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, fourier-series

> Show that the partial sum in equation (3) may be written as:$$f_N(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^x \frac{\sin(2Nt)}{\sin(t)}\,dt$$

Can someone please explain me how to show these 2 are equal? The first step I can only think of is to use property of an even function.

Equation (3): 
$$
f_N(x) = \frac{4}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\sin((2n-1)x)}{2n-1}
$$

Comment: possible duplicate of [Computing $\zeta(6)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{k^6}$ with Fourier series.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115981/computing-zeta6-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1k6-with-fourier-series)

Comment: Why is this question downvoted that much?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Partial Sum Fourier Series](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1181436/partial-sum-fourier-series)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1181436/partial-sum-fourier-series/1182254#1182254


Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that both terms of the desired identity vanish at $x=0$, then **by differentiating** (*a finite sum and a primitive*), it is sufficient to prove that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{N} \cos ((2n-1)\theta)=\frac{\sin (2N\theta)}{2\sin\theta}.\tag1
$$

To prove $(1)$, here are some possible steps:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{N} \cos ((2n-1)\theta)&=\Re \sum_{n=1}^{N} e^{i(2n-1)\theta}\\\\
&=\Re\left( e^{i\theta}\frac{e^{2iN\theta}-1}{e^{2i\theta}-1}\right)\\\\
&=\Re\left( e^{i\theta}\frac{e^{iN\theta}\left(e^{iN\theta}-e^{-iN\theta}\right)}{e^{i\theta}\left(e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}\right)}\right)\\\\
&=\Re\left( e^{iN\theta}\frac{2i\sin(N\theta)}{2i\sin\theta}\right)\\\\
&=\Re\left( \left(\cos (N\theta)+i\sin (N\theta)\right)\frac{\sin(N\theta)}{\sin\theta}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{\cos (N\theta)\sin (N\theta)}{\sin\theta}\\\\
&=\frac{\sin (2N\theta)}{2\sin\theta}.
\end{align}
$$